# Is it correct to say that the function $f(x)$ is everywhere continuous even if left side limit doesn't match with right side limit?

Tags: calculus, continuity

> If a function $$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{|x-4|}{x-4} & \textrm{ , } x\neq 4 \\ 0 & \textrm{ , } x=4  \end{cases}$$. Prove that $f$ is everywhere continuous except at $x=4$.

Rewrite $$f(x)=\begin{cases} -1 & \textrm{ , } x< 4 \\ 0 & \textrm{ , } x=4\\1 & \textrm{ , } x>4  \end{cases}$$

Now, $$\lim_{x\to4^-}f(x)\neq \lim_{x\to4^+}f(x)\neq f(4)$$, therefore $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=4$.

Again, rewrite,  $$f(x)=\begin{cases} -1 & \textrm{ , } x=3,2,1,0,-1,-2,... \\ 0 & \textrm{ , } x=4\\1 & \textrm{ , } x=5,6,7,8,9,10,....  \end{cases}$$ (interger values of $x$ are taken for convenience to understand)

I want to understand why (or how) $f(x)$ is everywhere continuous excluding $x=4$.Is it correct to say that $f(x)$ is evrywhere continuous even if $\text {L.H. Limit} \neq \text {R.H. Limit}$?

Any help or explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is discontinuous at $x=4$ because it has a jump. Everywhere else, it is well defined, with both the left and right limits equalling the function value at that point.

Comment: @AndrewLi, It is obviously discontinuous at $x=4$. But I want to uderstand the fact *well-defined*, that makes $f(x)$ continous everywhere.

Comment: Simple intuition: continuity means you can draw a line without lifting a pen.  For $f(x)$, you can do so for $x$ starting from $-\infty$ to $x=4$ (excluding 4) and from $x=4$ (excluding 4) to $\infty$. Yet you have to lift up the pen at $x=4$

Comment: See Semi continuity on Wikipedia.

Comment: @thevbm What are you talking about. If the RHL and LHL are different there is no continuity

Comment: LHS and RHS limits are the same for all $x<4$ and for all $x>4$

Comment: @AndrewLi that is my question if there is no continuity(LHL $\neq$ RHL) then there is no question of everywhere continuity.

Comment: @Vasya, LHL $-1$ and RHL $1$. would you tell me how are they same?

Comment: Pick any other point, say $5$. The left hand limit and right hand limit are the same here, both are equal to $1$. At some point less than $4$, these limits would be $-1$. The _only_ point at which they are different is at $4$ (where the function _is_ discontinuous)

Comment: @thevbm But your question says **everywhere except $x=4$**, no? That's true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any $x_0\ne4$. Then $f$ is constant in a full (maybe small) two-sided neighborhood of $x_0$, hence continuous at $x_0$. At $x_0=4$ the lefthand and the righthand limit of $f$ are unequal, hence $f$ is not continuous at $x_0=4$ (and cannot be made  continuous there by a clever redefinition of $f(4)$).

It is therefore absolutely correct to say that $f$ is everywhere on ${\mathbb R}$ continuous, except at $x_0=4$.

Comment: Thank you sir, it is now totally clear to me. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

This just my reply to your comment, but it is too large for the comment.

To "really see" that the limits are different, rewrite the function as
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{-x+4}{x-4} & \textrm{ , } x< 4 \\ 0 & \textrm{ , } x=4\\\frac{x-4}{x-4} & \textrm{ , } x>4  \end{cases}.$$

Take limits and observe that they are different.

Comment: Thank you, for your reply (+1).Also the confusion got cleared.